# how to delete the exact item in the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, data-structures

I want to delete the exact item in the array but pop will delete the last item. What can I do instead?

```js
const arr = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

var num = prompt("Enter a Number");
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var day = prompt("Enter Days: ");
  if (arr[i].includes(day)) arr.pop(day)
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why the number? To loop over only the first 3 days or so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use array.filter to remove unwanted entries from an array. It will leave the original array untouched and return a new array without the values.

`var filteredArray = arr.filter((innerDay) => innerDay !== day)`

Answer (score 3):

You could start of by prompting for the day you want to delete. Then loop over the array and if the item `includes()` it, you could use `splice()` to remove the specific item at the index of `i`.

```js
const arr = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

var day = prompt("Enter Day: ");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].includes(day)) arr.splice(i, 1)
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You firstly need to check if that element (day) is present in the array. If yes, you'll get its index. Use that to safely delete it using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). I assume the above is what you're trying to achieve. If you are looking for that day according to the order of your question numbers, probably you can follow @axtck's answer.

```js
const arr = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

var num = prompt("Enter a Number");
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var day = prompt("Enter Days: ");
  var index = arr.indexOf(day)
  if (index > -1) arr.splice(index, 1)
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`:

```js
const arr = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday',
    'thursday', 'friday', 'sturday', 'sunday'
]

function removeDay(arr, day) {
    return arr.filter(el => el !== day);
}
var day = prompt("Enter Day: ");
var newArray = removeDay(arr, day);
console.log(newArray);
```